# Conditions for invertibility of $AA^t$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix whose rows are pmfs (i.e. nonnegative entries, each row sums to $1$). Are there any conditions on $A$ weaker than invertibility such that $AA^t$ is invertible?

Comment: Square matrices? Then $AA^t$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is invertible.

Comment: What is *pmfs*?

Comment: @dear leader: probability mass functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $AA'$ is invertible iff $A$ has full row rank.

For convenience, let $B=A'$, then we are to investigate $B'B$, which is positive semidefinite. Then,
$$
B'B\text{ is invertible}\iff B'B\text{ is positive definite}\\
\iff\forall v\neq 0, 0<v'B'Bv=|Bv|^2\\
\iff\forall v\neq 0, Bv\neq 0\iff B\text{ has full column rank.}
$$
(Every $v$ above is a column vector with length equals to the number of columns of $B$.)